# <NuxtLayout> name prop not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vue-reactivity, vueuse

I have a component that should switch the used layout based on the current breakpoint.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue";
import { breakpointsTailwind } from "@vueuse/core";

const breakpoints = useBreakpoints(breakpointsTailwind);

const layoutName = computed(() =>
  breakpoints.smaller("md") ? "sidenav-mobile" : "sidenav-desktop",
);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ breakpoints.smaller("md") }} <!-- this is reactive -->
    <NuxtLayout :name="layoutName"> <!-- layoutName is not reactive -->
      <template #links>
        <slot name="links"></slot>
      </template>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

When resizing the window below or above the breakpoint, my debug output `{{ breakpoints.smaller("md") }}` correctly changes to true or false, but the layout does not switch unless I reload.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a ref. In templates they're unwrapped, so it works "as expected".

In your `computed` you need to add a `.value` to read the current value.

Comment: It was really as easy as that huh? The migration from Vue 2 with Options API to Vue3 with composition API is really not that easy. Thanks!

Comment: But it's gonna be awesome, once you get the hang of Composition API! Bite through it!